# Prove this set is not connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

I have this set

$A=\{(0,0,1),(0,0,-1)\}\subset \mathbb R^3$

How can I prove this is not path connected (or not connected)?

Thanks.

Comment: This problem is part of another problem Im trying to solve, and the only thing I have tried is by definition but Im not sure if I can do that.

Answer (score 2):

It's not connected by definition. ($A$ is a union of two disjoint nonempty open sets)

Path connected implies connected, so in the same way if it's not connected it's not path connected. And you are done!

**EDIT** you may think $\{(0,0,1)\}$ is a closed subset of $A$ - which it is. But by the subspace topology this means that $A\setminus\{(0,0,1)\} = \{(0,0,-1)\}$ is open. Similarly you can show that $\{(0,0,1)\}$ is open (so both of these subsets are clopen disjoint nonempty subsets).

Comment: Or just put an open ball of radius $1$ around both of them.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ can be expressed as the disjoint union of two open sets $U$ and $V$.

let $a=\{(0,0,1)\}$ and $b=\{(0,0,-1)\}$
Define $U=B_{\epsilon}(a)$ and $V=B_{\delta}(b)$ (open balls with radius $\epsilon$)

Now the trick is to find an $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ small enough that $U$ and $V$ are disjoint. Pick $\epsilon=1$ and recall the radius is $\epsilon=(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{1/2}$, and around $(0,0,1)$ we have $B_{1/2}(a)=\{(x,y,z):((x-0)^2+(y-0)^2+(z-1)^2)^{1/2}<1)\}$

Note that the point $\{(0,0,1/n)\}$ is contained in $U$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Now take $V$ to be the ball with radius $\delta=1$, and make a similar argument, this time for $-1/n$. The origin is contained in the union, and $U$ and $V$ are disjoint, with $a\in U$ and $b\in V$, so the set $A$ is not connected, and by contrapositive, cannot be path-connected. You also could have toyed around with $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ but setting them both to $1$ makes the argument neater.